# dhtmlx scheduler - how to use select bar in month view?

Tags: dhtmlx-scheduler

By default, dhtmlx scheduler uses a select bar for each event for week view:

http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_select_config.html

Is there a way to use it in month view?

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to show selection menu in month view. 
But you can enable 'Quick Info' extenstion, it provides a popup with the same functionality and can be used in all views.

Check the [example](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/samples/03_extensions/30_quick_info_detached.html) and related [docs](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/quick_info.html)

Comment: Nice alternative! Thank you

Comment: Hi, actually I tried to enable 'Quick info' extension, but now when I click in a day, I get an error: TypeError: scheduler.isOneDayEvent is not a function. Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: hi, most probably your js files (dhtmlxscheduler.js and dhtmlxscheduler_quick_info.js) are from different versions of the component. dhtmlxscheduler_quick_info.js is from version 4.0, while dhtmlxscheduler.js is probably from v3.7. The inner API's has became incompatible between version change. Try to use scripts from one package